# Python - Create lists from columns

Tags: python, list

How can I create from this (two columns, fixed width):

```
0.35    23.8
0.39    23.7
0.43    23.6
0.47    23.4
0.49    23.1
0.51    22.8
0.53    22.4
0.55    21.6
```

Two lists:

```
list1 = [0.35, 0.39, 0.43, ...]
list2 = [23.8, 23.7, 23.6, ...]
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 16):

Probably you are looking for something like this

```
>>> str1 = """0.35    23.8
0.39    23.7
0.43    23.6
0.47    23.4
0.49    23.1
0.51    22.8
0.53    22.4
0.55    21.6"""
>>> zip(*(e.split() for e in str1.splitlines()))
[('0.35', '0.39', '0.43', '0.47', '0.49', '0.51', '0.53', '0.55'), ('23.8', '23.7', '23.6', '23.4', '23.1', '22.8', '22.4', '21.6')]
```

You can easily extend the above solution to cater to any type of iterables including file

```
>>> with open("test1.txt") as fin:
    print zip(*(e.split() for e in fin))


[('0.35', '0.39', '0.43', '0.47', '0.49', '0.51', '0.53', '0.55'), ('23.8', '23.7', '23.6', '23.4', '23.1', '22.8', '22.4', '21.6')]
```

Instead of strings if you want the numbers as floats, you need to pass it through the float function possibly by map

```
>>> zip(*(map(float, e.split()) for e in str1.splitlines()))
[(0.35, 0.39, 0.43, 0.47, 0.49, 0.51, 0.53, 0.55), (23.8, 23.7, 23.6, 23.4, 23.1, 22.8, 22.4, 21.6)]
```

And finally to unpack it to two separate lists

```
>>> from itertools import izip
>>> column_tuples = izip(*(map(float, e.split()) for e in str1.splitlines()))
>>> list1, list2 = map(list, column_tuples)
>>> list1
[0.35, 0.39, 0.43, 0.47, 0.49, 0.51, 0.53, 0.55]
>>> list2
[23.8, 23.7, 23.6, 23.4, 23.1, 22.8, 22.4, 21.6]
```

So how it works

[zip](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) takes a list of iterables and returns a list of pair wise tuple for each iterator. itertools.izip is similar but instead of returning a list of pairwise tuples, it returns an iterator of pairwise tuples. This would be more memory friendly

[map](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) applied a function to each element of the iterator. So `map(float, e.split)` would convert the strings to floats. Note an alternate way of representing maps is through LC or generator expression

Finally [str.splitlines](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines) converts the newline separated string to a list of individual lines.

Comment: @user1969754: If the answer helped, accept it and try upvoting

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
splitted = columns.split()
list1 = splitted[::2] #column 1
list2 = splitted[1::2] #column 2
```

Comment: First you cannot slice a generator. Second this will not return the exact result, you probably meant `splitted = column.split()`. Third , the slice should actually be written `splitted[::2]` and `splitted[1::2]`, Fourth may not work with all form of iterables, port your solution to use `islice`

Comment: thanks for the corrections. I didn't have an interpreter on my machine to test the code. Every day is a school day.

Comment: If you don't have Python in your local machine you can [IDEONE](http://ideone.com/ylPX64) it